# How to loop grid row data?

Tags: angular, typescript

I faced some problem that I wanna to track if second row of grid have data then the value will change to bold in (textbox readonly) . Means more than 1 items. I'm using loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < example[i] ['hello'].length; i ++)
{
  If (example[i] ['hello'].length > 0) {
    1. More than one row then textbox value must change to bold 
       but not all column does not need to have data. 

    2. If full row and all column have data then the textbox 
       will change to yellow color + bold. 
  }
}
```

*I'm a beginner at both of these tech and a bit confused to use loop sometimes may blur with using for and if together. Please explain detaily if you can, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things. First, to to be clear, your array looks like this

```
var example = [
   {
      "hello": [
        ["item 1", "item 2", "", "item 3"],
        ["item 1", "", "item 3", "item 4"] 
      ]      
   }
]
```

If your example object doesn't look like that, clarify, as needed.

Cleaning up your example and variables a little bit:

```
var tables = example;
for (var tableIndex = 0; tableIndex < tables.length; tableIndex++)
{
   var tableRows = tables[tableIndex];

}
```

Just looping through each grid in your example variable of grids.

Next, let's loop through the rows:

```
var tables = example;
for (var tableIndex = 0; tableIndex < tables.length; tableIndex++)
{
   var tableRows = tables[tableIndex];
   for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < tableRows.length; rowIndex++)
   {
      var rowCells = tableRows[rowIndex]
      var allCellsHavVal = rowCells.every(cellHasVal);//If every cell has a value
   }
} 

function cellHasVal(cell)
{
   return Boolean(cell);//return true if cell is 'truthy' (has a value);
}
```

We've done a couple things here:

1. Created a function has returns true if a cell has a value (named cellHasVal)
2. Created a loop that goes through every row in the table and assigns a value to a variable if every cell has a value.

Last step:
Loop through every cell in the row and format according to the rules:

```
var tables = example;
for (var tableIndex = 0; tableIndex < tables.length; tableIndex++)
{
   var tableRows = tables[tableIndex];
   for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < tableRows.length; rowIndex++)
   {
      var rowCells = tableRows[rowIndex]
      var allCellsHavVal = rowCells.every(cellHasVal);//If every cell has a value
      var shouldBold = rowIndex > 1; //If more than one row of data, bold the cell
      for (var cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < rowCells.length; cellIndex++)
      {
        if (shouldBold)
        {
         //bold cell (implementation can vary based on your toolset, style, etc.)
        }
        if (allCellsHaveValue)
        {
         //Turn background of cell yellow, 
        }
      }

   }
} 

function cellHasVal(cell)
{
   return Boolean(cell);//return true if cell is 'truthy' (has a value);
}
```